# Using xlst for multiple fileds

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

Im trying to reformat some xml using xlst but for one line i need to pull two different strings together, which is fine, but the second part only needs to contain "-GLOSS"

the xslt:

```
<productcode><xsl:value-of select="productcode"/><xsl:value-of select="components/component/componentcode"/></productcode>
```

the result:

```
<productcode>PRO-MAJ-CAN-A4L-HBHDBOOK.HDBOOK-GLOSS</productcode>
```

what i need

```
<productcode>PRO-MAJ-CAN-A4L-HB-GLOSS</productcode>
```

Where only "-GLOSS" is used and "HDBOOK.HDBOOK" is omitted

Comment: This is confusing. Please show us the XML input, or at least the two relevant elements. Also explain what is the **rule** for extracting the wanted part(s) from these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely guessing on my part, but I suspect you want to change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="components/component/componentcode"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(components/component/componentcode, '-')"/>
```